# Set an Image for a Label using an Image from an arraylist in GUI

Tags: java, image, user-interface

I have an ImageIcon array list that contains a couple of images.

When I try to set a label's icon to one of the pics from the array list nothing displays.

```
private ArrayList<ImageIcon> images = new ArrayList<>();
images.add(new ImageIcon("/images/image1.png"));
//Used to see that our list is not empty
System.out.println(images.size())

System.out.print(images.get(1));//Shows up blank
```

Comment: First index in any list is 0, you should print 'images.get (0);

Comment: And to check if the list is empty: `if (!images.isEmpty()) { System.out.println(images.get(0)); } else { System.out.println("No Images in ArrayList!"); }`